# Why is data not being transferred to my sink table after successfully completed Data Flow in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am very new to both SQL and Azure Data Factory and am trying to import some data from one table to another in the same azure sql database using azure data factory. To be able to use the data in my sink table, i need to transform some of the rows in the source. 
My flow looks like this:[Data flow in Azure data factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y6YN.png).

The dataflow executes successfully:
[Data flow results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5etC.png).
However, data rows are not being copied to my sink table.

I've even tried the "Recreate" table option on the sink, I can see that my column names in the sink table are being overwritten to match the source table, but still no rows are being transferred to the sink, they stay empty.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. In the alter row step of the data flow, I had an update condition first and insert condition second. When I removed "Update" as the first condition all data was successfully inserted in my sink table.
I originally thought that alter row step operated the conditions with an "OR" statement, but it seems it goes in order first to last statement. Since my first one was an update of the data that was not present in my sink table, it did not seem to jump to the insert condition at all.